# Only allow certain subclasses in relationship OO-design

Tags: c#, inheritance, dependencies, composition, object-oriented-analysis

I have a setup that currently looks kind of like this:
[image]

I have a **System** type that has 3 subclasses as you can see above. Each of these systems can have different types of authentication methods and a **System** instance will have an **Authenticator** instance. The idea is that certain systems can have their own authentication "strategies" as well as possibly use a generic strategy. However, each system should only be allowed to use the system-specific or certain "allowed" **Authenticators**.

So in the diagram **SystemA** can use **SystemA Quick Authenticator**, **System A Reuse Authenticator** and **Generic Authenticator 2**. **System A** should not be allowed to use eg. **Generic Authenticator 1** or any of the **System B Authenticator**'s. Likewise **System B** has a similar setup and System C is only allowed to use **Generic Authenticator 2**. This sort of works fine but fails as soon as I need to implement some base logic in **Base System A Authenticator** which **Generic Authenticator 2** will then need to implement as well.

I thought of using some sort of composition instead of inheritance and have like a **System A Auth Handler** which just links to a **BaseAuthenticator** and the use some domain logic to control that eg. a **Generic Authenticator 1** is never used. This however does not seem like a very nice solution either.

Do you have an idea for how I can achieve this sort of subclass "restriction" setup without having to do manual type checking and without comprosing OO principles (eg. interface segregation principle seems to be pretty much broken in the current setup..)?

Comment: Seems to me the obvious solution would be to add a common ancestor abstract class to `Generic Authenticator 2` and `Base System A Authenticator` instead of having them both inherit directly from `Base Authenricator`.

Comment: Hi Zohar, yeah so your point is that IF there should be any System A specific details they should go into the class that is currently called Base System A Authenticator? Becuase if they are needed in in Generic 2 then it is in fact not that generic at all.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much

Comment: I actually went with a slightly different solution. I made a System A Generic 2 Wrapper class that inherits from the current System A Base Auth. This way the generic classes are not dependent on classes (or interfaces) in the System A hierarchy even though the approach in general may result in some more classes. Thanks a lot for your help though Zohar, much appreciated, I was definitely aided by your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To those interested, I went with the following solution. I introduced a new System A Auth class to wrap Generic 2 Authenticator. It is not a perfect solution, but the Generic classes do not have any dependencies on the system-specific classes which in my case is quite useful.
[image]

A different approach as suggested by Zohar in the comments above could be to introduce a new abstraction level for System A (See illustration below). This approach of course favours reuse, but for my scenario it was more important that the generic classes had no dependencies to system specific classes.

[image]